# AWS QuickSight query provides S3 403 error, while buckets with same config are able to connect with QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I have 2 buckets in S3, where the second one is created with the settings of the first copied.
Both buckets are transformed into tables in Glue (in the same database, the first table via a crawler, the second manually created).
Both tables can be queried in Athena.
If I try to visualize the tables in QuickSight, the first table can visualized in graphs/etc.
If I try to visualize (or query in QuickSight) the second table. It gives me the error:

```
An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID:
```

How can I avoid this?

I suspect it has to do with the security settings of the second bucket (because if it would have to do with IAM roles or QuickSight, I would expect the first table also not to visualize). But I copied these settings exactly from the first table, which are the default settings (no public access, no policies, etc.).
I tried to add the same S3 bucket via a manifest file, which gives me the same error.

Anyone that had the same issue and knows where to look?

Any help would be great.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I see I had to change the allowed buckets in the IAM policy for QuickSightAccessForS3StorageManagementAnalyticsReadOnly (and Glue in my case)

Comment: can you share the details of how you did that please? thanks